# Setting time in UTC in the HTTP request

Tags: java, http, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I want to pass `current date` and `time` in `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss` format in HTTP request. I want my time to in 24 hrs format and timezone should be UTC. I'm currently using the function `${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss)}` which returns the time in `12-hour` format and timezone is being taken as local.

Can someone please help me, how can I get the time in `24-hour` format and set timezone as UTC in `Jmeter`.

Answer (score 1):

As of [JMeter 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html) you can get time only in default timezone using [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time), if you need to get the time in different timezone you can set [`user.timezone` Java System Property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/troubleshoot/time-zone-settings-jre.htm) under *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.

If your test assumes generating timestamps in different time zones, to wit the above approach is not an option you can consider switching to the [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) which allows executing arbitrary Groovy code

1. Current timestamp in the default time zone:

   ```
   ${__groovy(new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"),)}
   ```
2. Current timestamp in UTC time zone:

   ```
   ${__groovy(new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss"\,TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")),)}
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSR223 component](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to calculate time using timezone

```
import java.time.*
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
LocalDateTime  today = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of( "UTC"));
log.info(today.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")));
```

Or one (long) liner

```
${__groovy(import java.time.*;import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of( "UTC")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")))}
```